# 1980's young-adult Television show - crashed alien ship (possible A.I)

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I'm trying to identify an old show.  Late 1980s, possibly 90s.

Details that I can remember are as follows -

Set on a farm, surrounded by woodland and near a swamp.

Involved a long-crashed alien ship (possible A.I), fragments are hidden over the area.

One part, utilised by the farm as a weather-vane on a barn.  The show frequently shifted point of view to the weather-vane as it watches the area.

The main character, teenage female, is the one trying to find the components (possibly under the influence of the alien) to reassemble the ship.

Might be Australian in origin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Children of the Dog Star](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0271902/)

Plot on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dog_Star).

> "On holiday at her uncle's **farm in New Zealand**, Gretchen befriends
>   Ronny, a Māori boy with a troubled city past, and Bevis the
>   birdwatching son of a loathed developer. Tension is already high as
>   the developer wants to buy and drain **a local swamp** for a housing
>   estate, but Ronny's uncle is the guardian of a traditional Māori tapu
>   (taboo/curse) upon the swamp. The swamp must not be touched—something
>   sleeps there that must not be awakened. Something unnatural."
>   "In the story, twelve-year-old Gretchen has a passion for science and
>   a talent for all things mechanical, which is why the **strange old brass
>   "weathervane" (referred to as the "daisy rod") on her uncle's farm
>   fascinates her**. But the brass daisy rod has a complex and terrifying
>   significance, and Gretchen and her new friend Ronny discover its links
>   with the far distant Sirius, the Dog Star."
>
> "Gradually, the children discover the **pieces of an ancient alien space
>   probe**
>   named Kolob. **During the series they assemble the missing parts** and
>   strange things start to happen. The probe was one of three sent to
>   earth to educate the human race in science. In the end a communication
>   link is set up with the star Sirius B, from where the probe came, and
>   the aliens tell them they should not have interfered."

You can watch Episode 1 here, ca. at 0:02:55 you can see the weathervane: